# Can you still update Windows tiers

Tags: windows-7, windows, bitlocker

I need to deploy BitLocker to 30 computers and these machines run Windows 7 Home and I was curious if it is still possible to update to Ultimate or will these machines need to go Windows 10?

Comment: If you have 30 Windows 7 Ultimate Licenses then it is indeed possible.  You might find it cheaper to go to Windows 10 Professional though.

Comment: Can you still buy the licenses or upgrade from within Windows? I know with 8.x microsoft forces you to go 10. I don't have access to a Windows 7 machine at this time to check

Comment: You will have to purchase Windows 7 licenses from a third-party.  Microsoft is not selling them currently, nor can you perform the Anytime Upgrade, at this time since its not sold.  You can perform the upgrade itself i you have a license.